# Turning off slices in Photoshop's "Save for Web & Devices" without deleting them

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices, export

I have a document set up with slices in Photoshop. If I want to export the whole PSD as one large JPG and no other files, can I do it?  I don't see any option to select combine all the slices into one just while exporting.

If I hide the slices with the View menu, it doesn't seem to make a difference once I get into 'Save or Web & Devices'. I know I could do this with 'Save As', but I like the ability to resize the exported image right there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would cheat. Clear slices, save for web, undo until you have your slices back, and then save that state of the file.

What I usually do is duplicate the final file and make a "slice" version, and save slices out of that. My original PSD is never sliced to begin with.

Comment: I think cheating in this or some other way is the only way to go if you want to meet all the question's requirements.

Comment: What a horrible workflow. Time to implement a new feature I'd say.

Answer (score 9):

I am sure one of these will work for anyone who has above issue:

1. Go to **View** → ***Clear Slices*** (last option)
2. Make sure that the Slice Tool is not selected while saving for web
3. Open up the Save for Web menu
4. Click the **Optimize Menu** (icon parallel to "Preset:" drop down in the top right (small drop menu icon)), select ***Edit Output Settings...***
5. Make sure you have set the settings to default - OR make it Custom and under the **Background** dropdown, set ***View Document As*** to "Image".

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Go to View → Clear Slices (last option)  this is helped me thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just a suggestion, you could "copy merged" then open a new file (this will already have your image size so just hit enter), paste, then "save for web and devices". This way you don't have to have two Photoshop files to maintain; you can just save the entire image as the optimized version you need.

To specifically answer your question, there isn't a way to save the entire image once it has been sliced up again unless you do what another person's suggestion was and make a slice of the entire image all together. I find that with keyboard shortcuts that my first suggestion takes only a few seconds and you get the result that you need.

Keyboard shortcuts (Windows):

1. Select All — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Copy Merged — <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. New File — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Paste — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
6. Save for Web and Fevices — <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: This is definitely how I do it. In fact, I have some actions set up to make it even quicker. Definitely the best method, just be ensure the new document has the same color profile.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Save For Web", instead use **File** → ***Save As...*** and then choose JPG, PNG, etc from the Format menu.

Comment: This is NOT the same thing as saving for web. The JPEG algorithm is different, for one thing. You have better optimization (smaller file size for similar quality) using Save For Web.

Answer (score 3):

Easy. Make a slice that would contain all of your composition(or the part that you require), then place this slice on top of your other slices, either via context menu option "Bring to Front", or by clicking on gliph placed on Options pannel. Slices placed below don't affect those placed a top, thus doesn't devide it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just "file save as"the whole psd as a .jpg, or "save for web devices" then choose .jpg file type?

Comment: I mentioned in the question I want to resize while saving as one step ideally. In save for web and devices choosing jpg will still use the slices as they are in the document

Answer (score 0):

The select all and then copy merged method works the best.

If you set up slices on a Photoshop document, it's probably because you're working something like an email and the slices need to remain so you don't have to re-slice every time you make an edit. The only problem is, it disables your ability to quickly save out a JPG/PNG mockup of the entire document. And unfortunately, there's no "save without slices" option in the Save for Web dialog.

The main reason you wouldn't want to do a "Save As" and go to JPG is because the workflow when saving several mockups becomes bogged down with options that require mouse clicks and navigation to save on them in the same place. Copy Merged has the advantage of swift keyboard shortcuts.

The reason you wouldn't want to clear slices is because you'd risk accidentally saving the file with the cleared slices and closing it before you realized what happened.