# How do I save this as single image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

When I do "Save to web and devices..." it shows me the below screen. When I try to save this, it saves it as separate part images. I want to this as a single image. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: I believe [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/46/4216) from a couple years ago still has the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of slicing crop, then save...

Answer (score 0):

Just do "Save us". "Save to web and devices..." is used to save a jpeg format to a web and cellphone platform, it lets you compress the image for web dissemination.